# PDO prepared statement wont execute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok, I am so frustrated, I have no idea what this problem is. I feel like such a bad programmer. I am trying to update my database, and I know that the table I'm trying to update exists. Literally I know that this query is accurate, but I have no idea why it isn't working. The first mysql statement executes but the second one doesn't. Here's my code.

```
$Statement = $Database->prepare("INSERT INTO table1 (tbl2id, col, col2) VALUES (?, ?, ?); UPDATE table2 SET this = ? WHERE id = ?");
$Statement->execute(array($table2id, $col, $col2, 1, $table2id));
```

So I'm trying to set up the databases so they're kind of connected. I made up all of the column names by the way. I don't know if it helps with security but I don't like posting that stuff in public. Anyways the 'this' column is 0 by default, and if it is made 1 it means that the user has responded. So 'this' is set up as a tinyint and has a default value of 0.

I don't mean to ask a stupid question or anything, and I hate to admit it but I seriously can't figure it out. Maybe there is something about PDO statements I don't know. I also tried running two separate executions, it still wouldn't do it. And I know someone is going to say that I'm not updating the right table or something. But I swear it is correct, I've checked at least 10 times.

Thank you so much. I like to figure stuff out on my own, but I can't waste anymore time on this.

Comment: What happens if you split it into two queries?

Comment: I did that, and it still wouldn't execute, I read up about PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES and I know it's set to 1 by default, and I haven't messed with it so I don't believe that's the problem

Comment: I mean, obviously there  may not be enough information from my post to be able to solve the problem, and I know that the code I posted seems to not have any errors. I'll keep trying to fix it, but I just want to make sure that there isn't anything wrong that's happening that's obvious. Like something with PDO that I don't know about and I'm stressing over.

Comment: Have you enabled all the error logging possible?

Comment: have you tried adding a try/catch

Comment: Yes, and I have made sure that PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES was false and that PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION were both called. It returns no error. I am so dumbfounded haha.

Comment: what about removing the ?'s and hardcode the values into the ?'s

Comment: I changed it to "UPDATE table2 SET this = 1 WHERE id = 5" and it still wouldn't work. I also tried running just changing the value in phpMyAdmin by hand. this is the query it ran "UPDATE  `database`.`table2` SET  `this` =  '1' WHERE  `table2`.`id` =5;" i apologize if it's hard to read, but it seems to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is one thing that really belongs to your programming skills.
A programmer have to **look for the error message** in the first place.
Instead of just sitting and looking at the code, a programmer have to **ask their program what's going on**.
So, it have to be your first and foremost concern - "How can I get an error message?".
Look, it's essentially different: not "what's wrong with my code?" but "how to get an error?".

Are you positively sure that `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is set and you can see all the errors occurred? Don't you have a silly exception handler with empty catch()? Do you have display_errors enabled (or have you checked logs)?
Can you see an intentional error - does a query like "blah foobar nonsense" raise one?

If not - take care of the error reporting matters.
If so - well, it's time to check some of your program flow logic and silly typo-like errors (like inserting in one database while checking another and such).

And yes, prepare/execute do not support multiple queries, you have to make them in separate calls